# prolog list error

Tags: prolog

```
?- last([a s d],X).
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: last([a 
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: s d],X) . 

last(X,[X]).
last(X, [_|L]) :- last(X,L).
```

The problem is to find last element in a list.But am getting above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the query change the order of the operands and use ','(comma) to separate elements of the list.
use query below:

```
?-last(X,[a,s,d]).
```